# Looking for correct drive for my PowerBook 400 MHz Pismo

Tags: mac, hard-drive, powerbook

This is the drive I have in my [Pismo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_G3#PowerBook_G3_.28FireWire.29) 400 MHz Mac Powerbook: *[IBM Travelstar 20 GB - 66.6 MBps - 4200 rpm](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1006&bih=645&q=djsa-210&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=1778704896219061225&sa=X&ei=udlbT8WiIcnm0QH3xszjDw&ved=0CEEQ8wIwAA#ps-sellers)*.

I would like to upgrade to a larger drive as I'd like to partition it, one partition for Mac OS X and the other for system 9.2.1.

How big a drive can I put in here, at the fastest speed that I can use? (The current one is 4200 RPM...a 5400 RPM would be fine.)

I also understand that the drives that go in this machine are [Ultra ATA/66s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#Features_introduced_with_each_ATA_revision).

Answer (score 0):

That drive has some issues apparently, I [found a little article](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/pb_g3/wallstreet_hard_drive/) over here about using Pismo's with that model, and it says:

> Many PB Wallstreet owners have reported that after installing an IBM
>   Travelstar drive the iPowerBook would not wake from sleep after
>   closing the lid.

I recommend viewing the full article, it does tell of some limitations, such as the 128GB limit.

I found [a great tool over here](http://forums.xlr8yourmac.com/drivedb/search.drivedb.lasso) that will find reviews of hard drives for any Apple Mac product you want, and give you model numbers. All the reviews are very comprehensive, and include a ton of information, including errors. Your laptop model is in there, and appears to have a few options.